# How do i open srt file on flutter?

Tags: flutter, video-player, subtitle, srt, flutter-video-player

I am trying to load subtitle to a video using the flutter video player package it works good for short files but it stopped as the file get bigger
I trayed subtitle_wrapper package but it has many bugs

```
Future<ClosedCaptionFile> getSubtitle(String url) async {
  final data = NetworkAssetBundle(Uri(path: url));
  final newdata = await data.load(url);
  String fileContents = getStringFromBytes(newdata);
  return captionFile = SubRipCaptionFile(fileContents);
}
```

this is getStringFromBytes function

```
getStringFromBytes(ByteData data) { final buffer = data.buffer; 
var list = buffer.asUint8List(data.offsetInBytes, data.lengthInBytes);
return utf8.decode(list); }
```

Comment: How about this package https://pub.dev/packages/subtitle?

Comment: @Majid i will try it now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it wasn't the size after all I tested on some srt files that have a blank space for some duration and the flutter converter do a check on every element if the length is<3 it break on get out of the loop